# Greyscale background image, but not content

Tags: html, css

I tried using this technique

```
<div class="grayscale"><span style="color:red">Red Text</span>

 .grayscale {
     background: url(yourimagehere.jpg);
     -moz-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
     -o-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
     filter: gray;
     filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
 }
```

It works well on background image, but also greys out all contents of the box. Is there any way to grey background only but keep contents full color? Thanks!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4nWd/1/)

Comment: A fiddle would be nice to see what's going on

Comment: @skyisred - http://jsfiddle.net/y4nWd/2/.. what I've done is (1) get the span out of the grayscale-div and put them both in a surrounding div. (2) Then make the span position relative and the top minus 'grayscale-img_height' (this only works if you know the height of the image obviously)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/apply-a-filter-to-a-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, as seen [here](https://css-tricks.com/apply-a-filter-to-a-background-image/)

You'll need to make your background image as the `:before` element, then the greyscale filter won't be applied to the children.

HTML

```
<div class="module">
  <div class="module-inside">
    Module
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.module {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: #ff43ea;
  position: relative;
}
.module::before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494645009625-cc17363a5f20?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=bd502af39c922553e5a13624d4f44f40);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.module-inside {
  position: relative;
  font: bold 42px sans-serif;
}
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/GXeQyJ

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the greyscale to the entire div with the class greyscale. This means that everything inside the div will comply. Therefore, you need to take your content (the span) out of the greyscale div and use css positioning to overlay the content on the image.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost what @chris said. Taken from http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/:

> A computed value of other than none results in the creation of a
>   stacking context [CSS21] **the same way that CSS opacity does**. **All the
>   elements descendants are rendered together as a group with the filter
>   effect applied to the group as a whole**.

You can, for instance, take the text out of your div and place it with absolute positioning.